# Setter injection doesn't work in Symfony 2 with Buzz browser client?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, ssl-certificate, buzz

I'm using [kriswallsmith/Buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/) browser inside my custom service `Skebby`. Here is `config.yml`, please note the call to `setVerifyPeer(false)` to disable SSL certificate verification:

```
# cURL client
buzz.client.curl:
    class:  Buzz\Client\Curl
    public: false
    calls:
    - [setVerifyPeer, [false]]

# Buzz browser configured to use cURL client
buzz.browser:
    class:     Buzz\Browser
    arguments: ['@buzz.client.curl']
```

While `Skebby` itself is annotated with [schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle):

```
/** @Service("skebby") */
Class Skebby
{
    /**
     * @InjectParams({
     *     "browser"    = @Inject("buzz.browser"),
     *     "translator" = @Inject("translator")
     * })
     *
     * @param \Buzz\Browser $browser
     * @param \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator $translator
     */
    public function __construct(Browser $browser, Translator $translator)
    {
        $this->browser    = $browser;
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function getCredit()
    {
        var_dump($this->browser->getClient());
        die();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the call (inside a controller) `$this->get('skebby')->getCredit()` shows that something wrong happened with the service container:

```
object(Buzz\Client\Curl)[4905]
  private 'lastCurl' => null
  protected 'options' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'ignoreErrors' => boolean true
  protected 'maxRedirects' => int 5
  protected 'timeout' => int 5
  protected 'verifyPeer' => boolean true
```

That is `verifyPeer` is still `true`, as the call `setVerifyPeer(false)` never happened. Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Useful links:

- [`AbstractClient.php`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Client/AbstractClient.php) the abstract client class
- [`AbstractCurl.php`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Client/AbstractCurl.php) parent class for cURL client, extending `AbstractClient`
- [`Curl.php`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Client/Curl.php) the class itself, extending `AbstractCurl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong indentation under `calls` directive

Should be:

```
buzz.client.curl:
    class:  Buzz\Client\Curl
    public: false
    calls:
        - [setVerifyPeer, [false]]
```

In your version it calls nothing ;)